# Multiple Vertical alignment on two rows

Tags: beamer, spacing, vertical-alignment, line-spacing, white-space

I making a presentation using beamer. My question is simple. How can I align 2 rows in 2 different part ?
I have in the 1° slide this:

```
Advisor: Prof. Latex Tex
Co. Advisor: Prof. Tex Latex
```

And this is the code:

```
\\\small \hspace{-0.6cm} Advisor: Prof. Latex Tex
    \\\small Co. Advisor: Prof. Tex Latex}
```

But I want as result:

```
Advisor:     Prof. Latex Tex
Co. Advisor: Prof. Tex Latex
```

When I add another `\hspace{}` after Advisor the results is completely messy.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

{\small
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Advisor:& Prof. Latex Tex \\
  Co. Advisor:& Prof. Tex Latex
\end{tabular}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, using `\makebox[<above>][l]{..}` with the help of `\widthof` from the `calc` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
  {\small\makebox[\widthof{Co. Advisor: }][l]{Advisor: }Prof. Latex Tex \par   
  Co. Advisor: Prof. Tex Latex}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]